# How to insert data via ajax jquery and show the query?

Tags: php, ajax

Want to run my insert query and after inserting into mysqli database, then want to show the same data in the same page.

Comment: do you have any code to show us what you have tried?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As written, this question is off-topic, as it's very broad and unclear what, specifically, you're having an issue with. It can also be seen as "write this code for me." And StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service. It's just a volunteer-run programming q&a site.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you're saying but without any code no one can really help you, luckily for you, I speak your language of not being clear when asking something so this is basically what you're asking for.

**HTML**

```
<form id="form_id_form" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="textbox1" id="textbox1">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<div id="insert_output"></div>
```

**AJAX**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#form_id_form").submit(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "path_to_your_insert_query.php",
            data: $("#form_id_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
            success: function(data) {
                $("#insert_output").html(data); // append insert query response to div id
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });
</script>
```

But really you should show us what your insert query looks like so we can better help you.